# Varnish not starting errors in syntax

Tags: wordpress, caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

I am scratching my head trying to figure out what is wrong with the syntax in my .vcl file. I keep getting the error:

```
Symbol not found: 'req.method' (expected type BOOL):
('input' Line 13 Pos 9)
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
--------##########--------------

Running VCC-compiler failed, exit 1
```

I am following along in this tutorial https://www.varnish-software.com/blog/step-step-speed-wordpress-varnish-software

Can anyone spot what I did wrong?

This is the file in its entirety:

```
    # This is a basic VCL configuration file for varnish.  See the vcl(7)
# man page for details on VCL syntax and semantics.
# 
# Default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content
# server.
# 
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
    if (req.http.X-Purge-Method == "regex") {
        ban("req.url ~ " + req.url + " && req.http.host ~ " + req.http.host);
        return (synth(200, "Banned."));
    } else {
        return (purge);
    }
    }

    if (req.url ~ "wp-admin|wp-login") {
    return (pass);
    }

    set req.http.cookie = regsuball(req.http.cookie, "wp-settings-\d+=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.cookie = regsuball(req.http.cookie, "wp-settings-time-\d+=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.cookie = regsuball(req.http.cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    if (req.http.cookie == "") {
    unset req.http.cookie;
    }    
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (beresp.ttl == 120s) {
    set beresp.ttl = 1h;
    }
}

# 
# Below is a commented-out copy of the default VCL logic.  If you
# redefine any of these subroutines, the built-in logic will be
# appended to your code.
# sub vcl_recv {
#     if (req.restarts == 0) {
#   if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
#       set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
#       req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
#   } else {
#       set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
#   }
#     }
#     if (req.request != "GET" &&
#       req.request != "HEAD" &&
#       req.request != "PUT" &&
#       req.request != "POST" &&
#       req.request != "TRACE" &&
#       req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
#       req.request != "DELETE") {
#         /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
#         return (pipe);
#     }
#     if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
#         /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
#         return (pass);
#     }
#     if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
#         /* Not cacheable by default */
#         return (pass);
#     }
#     return (lookup);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_pipe {
#     # Note that only the first request to the backend will have
#     # X-Forwarded-For set.  If you use X-Forwarded-For and want to
#     # have it set for all requests, make sure to have:
#     # set bereq.http.connection = "close";
#     # here.  It is not set by default as it might break some broken web
#     # applications, like IIS with NTLM authentication.
#     return (pipe);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_pass {
#     return (pass);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_hash {
#     hash_data(req.url);
#     if (req.http.host) {
#         hash_data(req.http.host);
#     } else {
#         hash_data(server.ip);
#     }
#     return (hash);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_hit {
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_miss {
#     return (fetch);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_fetch {
#     if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
#         beresp.http.Set-Cookie ||
#         beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
#       /*
#        * Mark as "Hit-For-Pass" for the next 2 minutes
#        */
#       set beresp.ttl = 120 s;
#       return (hit_for_pass);
#     }
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_deliver {
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_error {
#     set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
#     set obj.http.Retry-After = "5";
#     synthetic {"
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
# <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
#  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
# <html>
#   <head>
#     <title>"} + obj.status + " " + obj.response + {"</title>
#   </head>
#   <body>
#     <h1>Error "} + obj.status + " " + obj.response + {"</h1>
#     <p>"} + obj.response + {"</p>
#     <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
#     <p>XID: "} + req.xid + {"</p>
#     <hr>
#     <p>Varnish cache server</p>
#   </body>
# </html>
# "};
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_init {
#   return (ok);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_fini {
#   return (ok);
# }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using varnish 3.x rather than 4.x: Replace `req.method` with `req.request`

```
if (req.request == "PURGE") {
```

Comment: I am using the varnish 4.0.3 still I am getting this error.